# SQL Server Express "hangs", on startup

Tags: sql-server, sql, windows-installer, sql-server-2012, sql-server-express

I recently installed SQL Server 2012 "Express", and, also, Visual Studio 2012.

I was working with it, and all worked ok.

At some point, a few hours ago, SQL Server Express, however, started "hanging", on Startup. I have tried uninstalling, and, then, installing, again, all the components, and, am, still, facing the same "hanging" on Startup.

Anyone have any ideas, what can be done?

Operating System is Windows 7-64 bit, and, the package of installation is "SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe" (although, I do not think, that that matters ;)).

Additional Note: At some point, I think, yesterday, Visual Studio 2012 wouldn't start up, either. Then, Visual Studio said, I would have to download a product "Update", which I did. I can not say FOR SURE, but, maybe, it is related to the SQL Server hanging?

Again, Anyone, any ideas?

Here is a screenshot of what I can see, on my screen:

[image: enter link description here]

However, I can't click ANYTHING, in the management "console"/"studio". It just, does not respond, to anything.

Comment: The connect window isn't off the screen is it? Push alt+space to move it back.

Comment: Thanks, ta, for your suggestion. But, unfortunately, that isn't the case :S

Comment: I have the last two, error logs, at:[link](http://www.sendspace.com/file/rs7p69)(ErrorLog, 7/23/13, 1 AM), and [link](http://www.sendspace.com/file/q83u32)(ErrorLog.1 7/22/13, 9:51 AM)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing happen the other day. Try restarting your computer in safe mode then opening SQL Server Management Studio. Then restart as normal and it should start working again. That worked for me.